# 「わけもないというふうで」What is the nuance being conveyed in this context?

Tags: grammar, words

From 銀河鉄道の夜（宮沢賢治）

「 さあ 」 ジョバンニ は 困って 、 もじもじ して い ましたら 、 カムパネルラ は わけ も ない と いう ふうで 、 小さな ねずみいろ の 切符 を 出し ました

「わけもないというふうで」What does this mean in the above context? Is カムパネルラ "acting as if there's no reason to be concerned"? What is the nuance being conveyed in this interaction?

Comment: It's showing the contrast between the mental states of the two characters. ジョバンニ is visibly discomfited and feeling awkward, while カムパネルラ is playing it cool, looking as if nothing is the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://reception.aozora.gr.jp/aozora/cards/000081/files/456_146.html

わけもない -- this expression used to be much more common -- esp. in books for young readers.

It means [ Very easy to do ] -- "as if it was the easiest thing" (in the world)

it's no trick to ...

> https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A8%B3%E3%82%82%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84-664927
>
> 訳も無い　ワケモナイ 　わけもない
>
> ①  たやすい。容易だ。訳はない。 「これくらいは－・いことだ」
>
> ②  理由がない。 「 － ・く涙がこぼれた」